# Using jQuery and an HTML5 form to populate the select field on a Marketo web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, marketo

Edit: Added a CodePenn to include a working example.

I'm taking a select choice from an HTML5 form and populating a Marketo Web form with its match.

Using some jQuery to get the value on the  html element and match it with the marketo form . Once I choose the option on form A, it selects the option on form B

Form A = regular HTML5 form

Form B = Marketo web form

The Marketo form has extra fields that are not in the HTML until you select an option. Once you pick an option, it will inject other fields into the form. If I select the option value manually, it works fine, but when the script adds the value to the Marketo form, it does not fire/trigger the same way.

Regular HTML5 Form markup:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <p><strong>I AM INTERESTED IN:</strong></p>
  <select id="select-iminterestedin" name="contact_iminterestedin" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

Matching the  option value on the second form:

```
  // populate the select field

  $('[name="contact_iminterestedin"]').on('change', function() {
    const selected = $(this).val();
    const matchValue = $(`#Initial_Product_Requested__c option[value="${  selected  }"]`);
    matchValue.prop('selected', true);
  });
```

CodePenn demo of the entire thing:

**https://codepen.io/bruno-gomes/pen/YbYBER?editors=0010**

So once I select the field on the HTML5 form it adds the selected option to the Marketo form. However this does not trigger the additional field that would show up in the marketo form. But if I select the field on the marketo form manually, this new field shows up.

I would like to know/understand if the method im using specifically does not work how I would expect, or if there is a different approach maybe missing something related to .trigger('change') or .click('change')..

Unfortunately I'm unable to provide the HTML for the Marketo form. It gets loaded into the site via marketo API.

Any tips or help is very much appreciated!
Kind regards.

Comment: $(document).on('change',''[name="contact_iminterestedin"]'',function(){
    const selected = $(this).val();
    const matchValue = $(`#Initial_Product_Requested__c option[value="${  selected  }"]`);
    matchValue.prop('selected', true);
  });



can you try this one, its because when the items are shown in the page the event handler is already binded to an element, so you want to register an event handler to the document it selfe rather than to a specific tag.

Comment: Seems there are parsing errors with that. @Rinor Dreshaj

Comment: can you check if that is firing though, than maybe its a problem inside your code?

Comment: $(document).on('change','[name="contact_iminterestedin"]',function() {

});


apperantly there were double quotes in it

Comment: @RinorDreshaj i was getting syntax erroes but i tried:
  ```$(document).on('change','name="contact_iminterestedin"]',function(){
    const selected = $(this).val();
    const matchValue = $(`#Initial_Product_Requested__c option[value="${  selected  }"]`);
    matchValue.prop('selected', true);
});
```
and that didnt work and also made it so the selected field did not change like it was doing before.
the new piece you updated still throws parsing errors. It makes the ```#Initial_Product_Requested__c``` not green anymore in the linter and it's yellow now and says Unexpected character '#'

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYpobb?editors=1010 try this, there is an explanation I did on the code

Answer (score 1):

To fire that out you need to add one more line with the: 
 `document.querySelector('#target').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

NOTE: Triggering event as a jQuery .trigger('change') not working in that case.

Based on your code it will look like:

```
$('[name="contact_iminterestedin"]').on('change', function() {
    const selected = $(this).val();
    const matchValue = $(`#Initial_Product_Requested__c option[value="${  selected  }"]`);
    matchValue.prop('selected', true);
    document.querySelector('#Initial_Product_Requested__c').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

---

Please note that it can be improved with the data attribute, since you have duplicates
in the code with the only change in #target selector.
Also using `$(document).on('change', '#source', function(){...});` will help if the #source element will be added to the DOM after the event listener initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on('change', '[name="contact_iminterestedin"]').on('change', function() {
        const selected = $(this).val();
        const matchValue = $(`#Initial_Product_Requested__c option[value="${  selected  }"]`);
        matchValue.prop('selected', true);
    });
```

that code should be registering the even handler on the document

Comment: No luck.

Here i put a codepenn together if you wanna take a look:
https://codepen.io/bruno-gomes/pen/YbYBER?editors=1100

if you change the <select> option on the left it will change the right to match. However, in my marketo form, selecting an option will spawn new <select> elements, and while the option inside the select changes, it does not trigger the new <select> to spawn.

Comment: So I tried the code in your penn, and it still has the exact same problem. The selected option populates the marketo form select, but it does not trigger the event that is supposed to come after (an extra <select> element being injected into the HTML). I'm trying to get an exact duplicate of the Marketo form I'm using and will follow up with that so you can see it for yourself. @Rinor Dreshaj

Answer (score 0):

Use [marketo's api](https://developers.marketo.com/javascript-api/forms/api-reference/) to update the form. You will need the form's `id` to get the form and then from there you can use `setValues` when the html field is updated to set the marketo form's dropdown value. This will ensure everything works as expected.

```
  $('[name="contact_iminterestedin"]').on('change', function() {
    const selected = $(this).val();
    const matchValue = $(`#Initial_Product_Requested__c option[value="${selected}"]`);
    matchValue.prop('selected', true);
    // get the form,
    const form = MktoForms2.getForm(3578);
    // set the form value you are interested in updating
    form.setValues({
      Initial_Product_Requested__c: selected,
    });
  });
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/hitscottys/pen/PobRZqx?editors=0001) for you.